# How do to "not equal" search using Windows Explorer (or perhaps another app) and then delete the found files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, find

on Linux/BSD, I can run

find my-path-here -not -iname "*txt" -type -f -delete

and this will delete all files that are not .txt files in the specified folder.

I want to do something similar on windows. Preferably not using powershell. :)

Thanks

Comment: What's the reason not to use PowerShell as it's probably the easiest option available that doesn't require additional software?

Comment: @seth thanks for asking. I find power shell overly complicated compared to Linux shell (normally bash).

Comment: I really think that's because you just haven't explored it/learned about it. I do agree that it can be complicated for certain things but looking for files is rather easy. I did post an example as an answer to show how to do it in this case. If you're already using an explorer alternative like TotalCommander or similar that might also give you some nice GUI options to do this.

Comment: @seth you're right. I'm more comfortable writing Bourne/bash scripts compared to Windows ones.

Comment: Install cygwin, it comes with bash. So you don't need to think about learning. GNUWin32 is also an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack) / [FileLocator Lite](https://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite) is perfect for this

> FileLocator Lite is a rebranding of Agent Ransack for corporate
>   environments. It has exactly the same functionality but with a
>   different name and logo

It is free for personal use.

Set `File name:` to `NOT: *.txt`

You can optionally search for `Containing text:`

Set `Look in:` to your path

Click `Start`

You can then select items from the results in the usual way (click, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+click, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+click etc.) and delete.

[image]

You can also configure it to react to <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to replace Windows Explorer Search:

```
Tools -> Shell Integration -> Replace default Explorer Search
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for a way to do this from the command line the for command may be helpful:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('dir /b /o') do @if not "%~xa" == ".txt" (@echo del: "%a") else (@echo keep: "%a")
```

Example:

[image: example for the above code]

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell would give you the advantage of being built-in (in modern Windows versions) and not requiring an additional tool. If you're not using an exclusion for your lookup the normal Windows Explorer search might also be sufficient. It does support some modifier to narrow your search.

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse | Where Name -notlike "*.txt" | Remove-Item
```

You might also be able to use Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) to actually us the same command, though you will find it does have some other issues and might not work exactly the same. In addition it would be kind of overkill for such a simple thing.

Comment: In your answer, where to do I supply the path? Or perhaps I need to be in the folder where I'm doing the search? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use it either way. The above example assumes you're already in the path. Otherwise use `Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Temp" -Recurse -File`. You could even omit the `-Path` but if you use it its more expressive (just a personal opinion).

Answer (score 1):

Use the minus sign to negate a search term in Windows Explorer.

For example, to search for files containing text *durp* and only showing files whos names are **not equal** to *dontFindMe.txt* you would use:

```
durp -name:dontFindMe.txt
```

After your search is finished you can just use Ctr+A to select all files and delete them

Answer (score 1):

[@BoldAsLove's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1638950/160219) helped me find [a official Microsoft page on File Explorer advanced searching](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference). It says its old, but I just tested the it working in Win10. Decoding your linux command (with help from `find` manpage) it seems you want to delete ALL files in a certain path/location that DON'T have TXT file extension (or end in TXT):

1. Open File Explorer. Navigate to folder where all your files are as the search takes less time & you don't have to give extra parameters
2. In top-right search click & type the following:

   `NOT .txt -kind:folder` OR `-name:*.txt -kind:folder`

   2a. I'm likely combining OLD & NEW syntax, but I tested it working in Win10. If you'd like to specify part of a filename just add it to the beginning: `zoom NOT .txt -kind:folder`
3. Ctrl+A (or click & drag to hightlight all files) then delete the files found by the search. File Explorer likely has no delete syntax, I like to think for good reason

Comment: WOW. This is very useful. Thanks!